# .htaccess redirect specific folder using RewriteCond% {TIME}

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to set up a time-based redirect with the .htaccess file.

More specifically, I would like to redirect a particular folder (eg. `test`) towards a specific URL as the temporal condition occurs, ie when it is that date.

Therefore, before the date the folder can be navigated without problems, while when the date is included in the condition, the user is directed to the URL.

I was trying to redirect a specific folder using `RewriteCond %{TIME}`.
However I can't get it to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{TIME} >=20211212100000
RewriteCond %{TIME} <20221216100000
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/test           [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/page$.php [R=301,L]
```

Is it possible to redirect the `test` folder to a URL (ex. `https://example.com/page.php`) passing that specific date? Some advice?

Comment: Thank you and I apologize for my bad English. Is that clear enough?

Comment: I tried, but does not work

Comment: Your rule will execute between 12th Dec 2020 and 16th Dec 2020 only. We are past that date

Comment: Obviously I changed the date. Thanks anyway

Comment: Place this .htaccess inside `test/` folder and it should work

Comment: If I put everything in the dedicated folder it works but in part. That is, if the user is on the /page.php page and updates, they are not redirected.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming these directives are in the root `.htaccess` file.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{TIME} >=20211212100000
> RewriteCond %{TIME} <20221216100000
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/test           [NC]
> RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/page$.php [R=301,L]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^$` only matches requests for the document root, so none of the conditions are going to be processed when `/test` is requested. (You can't request `example.com/` *and* `example.com/test`.)

You don't need the `RewriteCond` directive - the URL check should be performed in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

However, you have an erroneous `$` in the *substitution* string.

Also, you need to use a 302 (temporary) redirect, not a 301 (permanent) redirect. The 301 redirect is going to be cached persistently by the browser, so when the time period passes the browser will continue to redirect any user that was previously redirected - from cache!

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME} >=20211212100000
RewriteCond %{TIME} <20221216100000
RewriteRule ^test(/|$) https://example.com/page.php [R=302,L]
```

Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. The regex `^test(/|$)` avoids matching other URLs in the root that simply start with `test`.

(NB: I assume these date/times are just for testing? They are a year in the future and cover a period of over 1 year?!)

> If I put everything in the dedicated folder it works but in part. That is, if the user is on the `/page.php` page and updates, they are not redirected.

Where should they be redirected in this instance? Your criteria only states that when the user requests `/test/<anything>` they are redirected to `/page.php` (in that time period). If they request `/page.php` then nothing happens.

Comment: Good morning, thank you very much for your kind reply and I apologize for the delay. I take this opportunity to wish everyone a pleasant Christmas and happy new year.